# most commonly mispelled words via Google Trends

Tags: google-trends

I would like to reproduce this commonly misspelled words list from Google trends.

- https://www.cbsnews.com/news/what-are-the-most-commonly-misspelled-words-of-2018/
- https://www.cnet.com/news/google-trends-says-your-misspelled-words-include-beautiful/
- https://twitter.com/GoogleTrends/status/1001918307413438464

I don't work for Google. Is this possible for the typical end-user (i.e., just a person at home) to reproduce this chart with Google trends?

> Top searched "how to spell" words, by state. May 1 2017 to May 1 2018 ranked by search interest

[image]